# initial android project produces 4 errors

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Trying to initialize a new android project to work with in the eclipse ide for android.

Just the simple "Hello World" project which comes already made cannot even run. Instead, it gives four errors when starting a new project.

Errors are as follows:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.
styles_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line 75 Android AAPT Problem

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\android workspace\HelloWorld\appcompat_v7\bin\appcompat_v7.jar'
HelloWorld      Build path  Build Path Problem

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved
HelloWorld      Unknown Java Problem
```

Any ideas as to what would be causing this problem? Also how to go about fixing this issue?

Comment: make sure that you are using respective SDK for the API level defined in androidMnifest.xml

Comment: if you just want to run the straight away you can delete the two folders and run the app.